# Reading webpage as String but error occured

Tags: android, android-webview, android-service, android-xml, android-internet

Trying to read a webpage as an String this is my code :

```
    public class ReadWebPage extends Activity {
private EditText url_text;
private TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    url_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
}
public void myButtonClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.ReadWebPage:
        try {
            if (!url_text.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                textView.setText("");
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.getText().toString());
                // Get the response
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String response_str = client.execute(request,
                        responseHandler);
                textView.setText(response_str);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "URL String empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some error occured.");
            textView.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
        break;
    }
}
    }
```

As above i show my code using that code and trying to read some webpage as String but it is showing that error.

```
  03-03 22:37:45.088: I/System.out(1233): Some error occured.
   03-03 22:37:45.088: W/System.err(1233): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
  03-03 22:37:45.138: W/System.err(1233):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 -03 22:37:45.148: W/System.err(1233):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  03-03 22:37:45.158: W/System.err(1233):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
```

Comment: Paste logcat and improve your question with precise and to the point info.

Comment: i have already pasted that @codingcrow

Answer (score 0):

Android is telling you that you shouldn't be doing network operations on the UI thread. It doesn't want you to block the thread, and for good reason.

Try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. Put your HTTP request code in the `doInBackground()` method and update the `TextView` in the `onPostExecute()` method. You CANNOT access the UI thread from the `doInBackground()` method.

Here's a really basic example:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    private TextView textView;

    public MyAsyncTask(TextView textView)
    {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String url = params[0];
        // your HTTP request code goes here
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Use the class like so:

```
new MyAsyncTask(myTextView).execute(myUrl);
```

Comment: will you please give me a example of that since i am new in android development @Tyler M.

Comment: @RajatTrivedi Google it SO, is full of solutions for your problems.